# Cannot remove images from directory

Tags: php

I have written these scripts to delete files (image, in fact) in a directory but have the choice to decide which one to delete and view before hand. The `view.php` script seems to be working fine, however the `delete.php` doesn't seem to be functioning because the images are not removing.

here are the scripts:

view.php

```
<?php
    $path  = '../product-uploads/gloves/'; // path for each page
    $files = glob("{$path}*.*"); // Get the files
    $files = array_filter($files, 'is_file'); // Get rid of directories
    $dates = array_map('filectime', $files); // Get the creation times.
    $md5s  = array();
    array_multisort($dates, $files, SORT_NUMERIC); // in order of creation


    foreach ($files AS $file)
    {
        $hash = md5_file($file);
        if (!in_array($hash, $md5s))
        {    
            $md5s[] = $hash;
            echo "<img src=\"$file\" /> <br />
            <form action=\"delete.php\" method=\"post\">
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Name\" value=\"$file\">  
            <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\">
            </form>";
        }
    }
?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
    $path = '../product-uploads/gloves/';// images are here
    $Name = $_POST['Name'];

    $PathFile = $path.$Name;
    $PathFile = basename($PathFile);

    header('Location: view.php');
?>
```

Comment: In which line exactly are you deleting the file?

Comment: I can't see anything in either script that actually tries to do any deletion...

Comment: You are not doing anything to delete.  Try unlink(), which deletes a file.

Comment: @RobertSeddon-Smith Thanks, working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't remove the images in your delete.php

Use [unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.unlink.php) on pathfile.